# asp.net, javascript getElementById to linkbutton

Tags: javascript, asp.net

im using asp.net with c#.

I have a gridview and there is a TemplateField column. Inside the TemplateField column there is a EditItemTemplate, and inside EditItemTemplate the is a linkbutton(LinkButton1).

Im trying to do a getelementbyid on the linkbutton from a javascript function:

```
document.getElementById("<%= LinkButton1.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
```

But when compiling, I get the error: "The LinkButton1" does not exist on the current context.

The aspx gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="157px" Width="814px" 
             CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
             OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
             OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
             OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
             OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
              onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" Font-Size="Medium" 
            AllowPaging="True" onpageindexchanged="GridView1_PageIndexChanged" onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"     >
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
<EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
            Text="Actualizar" ValidationGroup="upd_validation"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
            Text="Cancelar"></asp:LinkButton>
</EditItemTemplate>      
<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
            Text="Editar"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete"
            Text="Eliminar" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' onclientClick="return ConfirmDelete()"></asp:LinkButton>                         
</ItemTemplate>                
</asp:TemplateField>
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the code of your aspx?

Comment: Yes. I just edited the main post with the aspx code.

Comment: Ok. It won't work that way, because your linkbutton is in a template actually. You won't have one but many linkbuttons, the code that uses the ClientID won't know which one to get. Explain what you want to do and I'll try to provide another solution.

Comment: On the gridview, when is on edit mode, there are also some textboxes to edit, if some textboxes do not match the required length, I want the linkbutton to be disabled, If the textboxes match the required lenghth, I want the linkbutton to be enabled.........How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can add some dummy css class to the LinkButton (example "disableLink"), and then using Jquery, u can easily achieve it using the below code

```
  $('.disableLink').each(function (i, obj) { 
      $(this).disabled = true;
      // OR
      $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#<%=grid1.ClientID%> td a").css("visibility","hidden");
  });
```